# How to mock existing endpoints in a CDI environment?

Tags: java, junit, apache-camel, cdi

I can't assert on mocked endpoints. I'm using JUnit and CDI injection in a WildFly container with Java DSL routes.

- I create a test class extending CamelTestSupport
- I inject a CamelContext field to use for stopping different components and for using advice
- I set useadvicewith so the context won't start by itself
- the test class inherits a context of type ModelCamelContext which seems to have NOHTING to do with my injected CamelContext field
- all the routes get created in the injected CamelContext field, not in the inherited ModelCamelContext
- however the whole mocking mechanism of CamelTestSupport uses exclusively the internal ModelCamel context

...so whatever I mock, is NOT what I advise :) and all assertions rightfully fail.

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class MyTest extends CamelTestSupport {
  @Override
  public boolean isUseAdviceWith() {
    return true;
  }

  @Inject
  private CamelContext camelContext;

  @Test
  public void someTest() {
    camelContext.getRouteDefinition("routeid").adviceWith(camelContext,
      new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure () throws Exception {
          mockEndpoints();
        }
      });
    Collection list = context.getEndpoints(); // the ModelCamelContext is always empty, looks bad
    Collection list2 = camelContext.getEndpoints(); // has both route endpoints AND mocks, looks good
    getMockEndpoint("mock:someid").expectedMessageCount(1); // will always CREATE a new endpoint in the empty modelcamelcontext
    getMockEndpoint("mock:someid", false).expectedMessageCount(1); // will always crash, that endpoint ID is in the other context...
```

I would give up the injected CamelContext but all the routes get created only there, I cannot tell why. The ModelCamelContext context of CamelTestSupport is ALWAYS empty... there's something I initialize differently/wrong but I cannot say what. Anybody used successfully Camel CDI test with mocks?

Comment: You can find docs here: [CDI testing](https://camel.apache.org/cdi-testing.html) and examples here: [Testing Example - CDI](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples/camel-example-cdi-test) (Switch the example to older branch, if you are not using Camel 3, there was some changes about advicing)

Comment: The tests are run by Arquillian and there's no example combining Arquillian and Camel CDI. May be because of the different test runners, but I have The Feeling(TM) that I get two camelcontexts - one initialized by camel-test and another by CDI, each one with half the functionality I need...

Comment: Yes `camelContext` is the managed one and `context` is initialized by `CamelTestSupport`. Dont extend test support and instead `getMockEndpoint("mock:xxx")` use `@EndpointInject(""mock:xxx"")`. Also to `mockEndpoints();` you should pass some pattern. Eg `mockEndpoints("file*");` or `mockEndpoints("*");` to mock all

Comment: Thank you, that injects something. But it's unusable for actual testing... after I try it like this, any assert will throw as unsatisfied even though I see logging has happened:
`@EndpointInject(uri="mock:seda:myqueue")
private MockEndpoint mock;
...
weaveById("myqueue").replace().log("perfect").to("seda:myqueue");
...
mock.expectedMessageCount(1);`

Comment: In case somebody reads this (or @Bedla, thanks again) the only workable way I found was skipping injection altogether:
`...
weaveById("myqueue").replace().to("mock:seda:myqueue").id("myqueue");
...
MockEndpoint mock = camelContext.getEndpoint("mock:seda:myqueue", MockEndpoint.class);
mock.expectedMessageCount(1);
...
mock.assertIsSatisfied();`